# What does the edit/update controller and form view look like for a nested form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I think my view is being structured incorrectly, but it was the only way I could get all the form fields to appear.

I'm trying to make a for that has two nested models. I know best practice is to have only one nested model, so I can't seem to find the solution for this problem.

My #edit page is only passing a single parameter for the double nested field. As a result, the #update controller is not properly updating the model.

View

```
## edit.html.erb
<%= form_for :question, url: scenario_question_path(), method: :patch do |f| %>
{{ ...error & non-nested inputs }}
  <ol>
    <% @question.answers.each do |fa| %>
      <%= f.fields_for :answers, fa do |ff| %>
        <li>
          <%= ff.text_field :answeroption %>
        </li>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </ol>
{{ submit }}
```

Controller

```
## questions_controller.rb
def update
    @scenario = Scenario.find(params[:scenario_id])
    @question = @scenario.questions.find(params[:id])

    if @question.update(params[:question].permit(:questionprompt, :text, answers: [:answeroption]))
      redirect_to scenario_question_path
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @scenario   = Scenario.find(params[:scenario_id])
    @question   = @scenario.questions.find(params[:id])
    @questions  = @scenario.questions.all
    @answers    = @question.answers.all
  end
```

The params being passed when Edit is submitted. The problem is that "answers" actually had more than one changed fields, but only the first one appears.

```
{"utf 8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"patch",
 "authenticity_token"=>"nvydgO4oxCo58y4gmRAJ5P8Kc+kmbqWGoQ0IjIuzYiQ=",
 "question"=>{"media"=>"test.jpg",
 "questionprompt"=>"123123123",
 "answers"=>{"answeroption"=>"2344634"}},
 "commit"=>"Save Question",
 "scenario_id"=>"1",
 "id"=>"1"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I outputted json and realized the model was structured in a different way than I realized. Also, the view was calling the same field 4 times, rather then calling four different fields.